# EHCache with Terracotta Vs Infinispan

Tags: ehcache, terracotta, infinispan

We are working in the design phase of new project where we need to decide the caching framework. We need decide whether to go with EHCache with Terracotta or Infinispan for caching requirement? Can anyone provide me the advantages & disadvantages of EHCache and Infinispan?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, Hazelcast has better performance that Infinispan. See [this](https://hazelcast.com/resources/benchmark-infinispan/). Note that the comparison was done by Hazelcast people, although I didn't see anything blatantly biased.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We were also in such an evaluation phase recently and decided for Hazelcast. In my opinion it is very easy to get started with. We needed a small solution with not very high traffic. They also provide a great support (I wrote a ticket and my problem was solved within one day!)

You should be clear if you want a server-based cache or a peer-to-peer solution as Infinispan or Hazelcast provides it.

Here you can find a short Hazelcast vs. Terracotta article: http://slava-technical.blogspot.com/2010/09/transparent-clustering-solutions.html

Answer (score 13):

Is your environment distributed?  If so, Infinispan would have an advantage of scalability due to its p2p design.  Even in standalone (non-clustered mode), you'd get to take advantage of the non-blocking nature of Infinispan internals, state of the art eviction algorithms ([LIRS](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.2184&rep=rep1&type=pdf&rct=j&q=LIRS&ei=sFrnTf3KL9O7hAfp9LCiCg&usg=AFQjCNFUDZi_nisWtbX1VXQ4jTAn-6LX-Q)), etc.  Have a look at [this article](http://infinispan.blogspot.com/2010/02/infinispan-as-local-cache.html) for a discussion of Infinispan as a local cache.

DISCLAIMER: I am the founder and project lead of Infinspan.